# Regression Analysis to estimate parameters Matlab

Tags: matlab, regression

I am trying to find perform a regression analysis to estimate

x = alpha + beta * y

where I want to find alpha and beta as I am using data for x and y.

```
P = [];
X = importdata('AAPL.csv',',');
P = [P X.data(:,5)];
X = importdata('BBBY.csv',',');
P = [P X.data(:,5)];
X = importdata('MMM.csv',',');
P = [P X.data(:,5)];
X = importdata('MSFT.csv',',');
P = [P X.data(:,5)];

X_return = P(2:end, :)./P(1:end-1, :) - 1;

F = [];
Y = importdata('IBM.csv',',');
F = [F Y.data(:,5)];

Y_factor = F(2:end, :)./F(1:end-1, :) - 1;


B = Y_factor\X_return;

X1 = [ones(length(Y_factor),1) Y_factor];
b = X1\X_return;
```

Where b returns my alpha and beta. However, I'm not sure if this is the correct way to approach this. I've tried to read up on some functions in Matlab that could do this, but didn't quite understand how to implement them. Is there a function in Matlab that could do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `regress` function to do your task as described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html) following good samples.

```
b = regress(y,X)
```

where b contains all your regression parameters.